# How to read Table Oriented Binary File in R with text based header

Tags: r, binary-data, read.csv

I am dealing with files containing variable length textual data in the beginning followed by binary data. Specifically it is a so called "Table Oriented Binary File".

Simply put the textual data functions as the header of the binary table, containing descriptive column names as well as datatypes which define the length of each value in the columns.

Since the binary data has no delimiter this length is used to read each datapoint one after the other.(more:  https://s.campbellsci.com/documents/us/manuals/loggernet34.pdf TOB1 section also small example below)

I came across an old repository(https://github.com/mlt/csdf.git) where the import was implemented (read.tob1.R) and started my approach from there because i also want to read TOB3 files which are similar but not implemented there.

The Import first loads the file in textmode

```
file.text <- file(file,"r")
```

to read the metainfo and the header with something like

```
header <- read.csv(nrow = 4)
```

While the file is read the byteposition is forwarded each time. After headers are read the byteposition is acquired with

```
pos <- seek(file.text)
```

This position is then assumed to be the end of the header and start of the binary data. Then the binary file will be loaded, set to the previous position

```
file.bin <- file(file,"rb")
seek(file.bin,pos)
```

and will be read from this position using dedicated functions for each datatype defined in the header. So For example first row is from type `ULONG` which is 4 Bytes long so the next 4 Bytes will be read while the position is forwarded automatically.

All easy and good....but

For some reason when reading with `read.csv()` the byteposition is forwarded more than seems to be the length of the rows.

If I read the first 4 lines of the textfile I end up at byteposition `3654` but when i read the same lines with readLines() from the binary file it ends up at `3152`. it seems that most of the offset happens when reading the first line and the the offset gets one byte smaller each line (See dump below). From Hexeditor and manually seeking the position in the file i know that the correct position to start from in the binary file is in fact `3152`.

Where does this difference come from and is there another way to find the start of the binary data? (I am on Windows 10)

```
> seek(testfile.text,0)
[1] 4096
> seek(testfile.bin,0)
[1] 95
> read.csv(testfile.text,header = FALSE,nrows = 1)
    V1    V2  V3   V4            V5                     V6    V7             V8
1 TOB1 Tower CR6 7562 CR6.Std.10.02 CPU:EasyFlux_Tower.cr6 22445 Flux_CSIFormat
> readLines(testfile.bin,n=1)
[1] "\"TOB1\",\"Tower\",\"CR6\",\"7562\",\"CR6.Std.10.02\",\"CPU:EasyFlux_Tower.cr6\",\"22445\",\"Flux_CSIFormat\""
> seek(testfile.text)
[1] 601
> seek(testfile.bin)
[1] 95
> 601-95
[1] 506
> read.csv(testfile.text,header = FALSE,nrows = 1)
       V1          V2     V3      V4    V5         V6 V7    V8         V9 V10  V11       V12
1 SECONDS NANOSECONDS RECORD FC_mass FC_QC FC_samples LE LE_QC LE_samples   H H_QC H_samples
     V13 V14 V15            V16                     V17         V18 V19    V20   V21   V22
1 NETRAD   G  SG energy_closure poor_energy_closure_flg Bowen_ratio TAU TAU_QC USTAR TSTAR
  V23      V24      V25        V26   V27       V28      V29      V30        V31 V32   V33
1 TKE TA_1_1_1 RH_1_1_1 T_DP_1_1_1 amb_e amb_e_sat TA_2_1_1 RH_2_1_1 T_DP_2_1_1   e e_sat
       V34      V35        V36     V37         V38       V39 V40 V41 V42      V43 V44
1 TA_3_1_1 RH_3_1_1 T_DP_3_1_1 e_probe e_sat_probe H2O_probe  PA VPD  Ux Ux_SIGMA  Uy
       V45 V46      V47     V48           V49           V50 V51     V52      V53      V54
1 Uy_SIGMA  Uz Uz_SIGMA T_SONIC T_SONIC_SIGMA sonic_azimuth  WS WS_RSLT WD_SONIC WD_SIGMA
  V55    V56         V57               V58         V59               V60                V61
1  WD WS_MAX CO2_density CO2_density_SIGMA H2O_density H2O_density_SIGMA CO2_sig_strgth_Min
                 V62 V63 V64   V65    V66   V67    V68      V69        V70         V71
1 H2O_sig_strgth_Min   P ALB SW_IN SW_OUT LW_IN LW_OUT T_nr_Avg LW_IN_meas LW_OUT_meas
      V72         V73           V74        V75             V76            V77     V78
1 PPFD_IN sun_azimuth sun_elevation hour_angle sun_declination air_mass_coeff daytime
       V79       V80            V81           V82            V83       V84      V85      V86
1 TS_1_1_1 SWC_1_1_1 cs65x_ec_1_1_1 G_plate_1_1_1 shfp_cal_1_1_1 FETCH_MAX FETCH_90 FETCH_55
       V87               V88            V89         V90
1 FETCH_40 UPWND_DIST_INTRST FP_DIST_INTRST FP_EQUATION
> readLines(testfile.bin,n=1)
[1] "\"SECONDS\",\"NANOSECONDS\",\"RECORD\",\"FC_mass\",\"FC_QC\",\"FC_samples\",\"LE\",\"LE_QC\",\"LE_samples\",\"H\",\"H_QC\",\"H_samples\",\"NETRAD\",\"G\",\"SG\",\"energy_closure\",\"poor_energy_closure_flg\",\"Bowen_ratio\",\"TAU\",\"TAU_QC\",\"USTAR\",\"TSTAR\",\"TKE\",\"TA_1_1_1\",\"RH_1_1_1\",\"T_DP_1_1_1\",\"amb_e\",\"amb_e_sat\",\"TA_2_1_1\",\"RH_2_1_1\",\"T_DP_2_1_1\",\"e\",\"e_sat\",\"TA_3_1_1\",\"RH_3_1_1\",\"T_DP_3_1_1\",\"e_probe\",\"e_sat_probe\",\"H2O_probe\",\"PA\",\"VPD\",\"Ux\",\"Ux_SIGMA\",\"Uy\",\"Uy_SIGMA\",\"Uz\",\"Uz_SIGMA\",\"T_SONIC\",\"T_SONIC_SIGMA\",\"sonic_azimuth\",\"WS\",\"WS_RSLT\",\"WD_SONIC\",\"WD_SIGMA\",\"WD\",\"WS_MAX\",\"CO2_density\",\"CO2_density_SIGMA\",\"H2O_density\",\"H2O_density_SIGMA\",\"CO2_sig_strgth_Min\",\"H2O_sig_strgth_Min\",\"P\",\"ALB\",\"SW_IN\",\"SW_OUT\",\"LW_IN\",\"LW_OUT\",\"T_nr_Avg\",\"LW_IN_meas\",\"LW_OUT_meas\",\"PPFD_IN\",\"sun_azimuth\",\"sun_elevation\",\"hour_angle\",\"sun_declination\",\"air_mass_coeff\",\"daytime\",\"TS_1_1_1\",\"SWC_1_1_1\",\"cs65x_ec_1_1_1\",\"G_plate_1_1_1\",\"shfp_cal_1_1_1\",\"FETCH_MAX\",\"FETCH_90\",\"FETCH_55\",\"FETCH_40\",\"UPWND_DIST_INTRST\",\"FP_DIST_INTRST\",\"FP_EQUATION\""
> seek(testfile.text)
[1] 1610
> seek(testfile.bin)
[1] 1105
> 1610-1105
[1] 505
> read.csv(testfile.text,header = FALSE,nrows = 1)
       V1          V2 V3         V4    V5      V6    V7    V8      V9   V10   V11     V12
1 SECONDS NANOSECONDS RN mg m-2 s-1 Grade samples W m-2 Grade samples W m-2 grade samples
    V13   V14   V15      V16 V17      V18        V19   V20   V21   V22    V23   V24 V25
1 W m-2 W m-2 W m-2 fraction  NA fraction kg m-1 s-2 grade m s-1 deg C m2 s-2 deg C   %
    V26 V27 V28   V29 V30   V31 V32 V33   V34 V35   V36 V37 V38   V39 V40 V41   V42   V43
1 deg C kPa kPa deg C   % deg C kPa kPa deg C   % deg C kPa kPa g/m^3 kPa hPa m s-1 m s-1
    V44   V45   V46   V47   V48   V49             V50   V51   V52             V53
1 m s-1 m s-1 m s-1 m s-1 deg C deg C Decimal degrees m s-1 m s-1 decimal degrees
              V54             V55   V56    V57    V58   V59   V60      V61      V62 V63 V64
1 decimal degrees decimal degrees m s-1 mg m-3 mg m-3 g m-3 g m-3 fraction fraction  mm   %
    V65   V66   V67   V68   V69   V70    V71                V72             V73
1 W m-2 W m-2 W m-2 W m-2 Klvin W m-2 W m-22 umolPhoton m-2 s-1 decimal degrees
              V74             V75             V76          V77      V78   V79 V80    V81
1 decimal degrees decimal degrees decimal degrees adimensional fraction deg C   % dS m-1
    V82 V83 V84 V85 V86 V87 V88 V89     V90
1 W m-2  NA   m   m   m   m   m   % authors
> readLines(testfile.bin,n=1)
[1] "\"SECONDS\",\"NANOSECONDS\",\"RN\",\"mg m-2 s-1\",\"Grade\",\"samples\",\"W m-2\",\"Grade\",\"samples\",\"W m-2\",\"grade\",\"samples\",\"W m-2\",\"W m-2\",\"W m-2\",\"fraction\",\"\",\"fraction\",\"kg m-1 s-2\",\"grade\",\"m s-1\",\"deg C\",\"m2 s-2\",\"deg C\",\"%\",\"deg C\",\"kPa\",\"kPa\",\"deg C\",\"%\",\"deg C\",\"kPa\",\"kPa\",\"deg C\",\"%\",\"deg C\",\"kPa\",\"kPa\",\"g/m^3\",\"kPa\",\"hPa\",\"m s-1\",\"m s-1\",\"m s-1\",\"m s-1\",\"m s-1\",\"m s-1\",\"deg C\",\"deg C\",\"Decimal degrees\",\"m s-1\",\"m s-1\",\"decimal degrees\",\"decimal degrees\",\"decimal degrees\",\"m s-1\",\"mg m-3\",\"mg m-3\",\"g m-3\",\"g m-3\",\"fraction\",\"fraction\",\"mm\",\"%\",\"W m-2\",\"W m-2\",\"W m-2\",\"W m-2\",\"Klvin\",\"W m-2\",\"W m-22\",\"umolPhoton m-2 s-1\",\"decimal degrees\",\"decimal degrees\",\"decimal degrees\",\"decimal degrees\",\"adimensional\",\"fraction\",\"deg C\",\"%\",\"dS m-1\",\"W m-2\",\"\",\"m\",\"m\",\"m\",\"m\",\"m\",\"%\",\"authors\""
> seek(testfile.text)
[1] 2400
> seek(testfile.bin)
[1] 1896
> 2400-1896
[1] 504
> read.csv(testfile.text,header = FALSE,nrows = 1)
  V1 V2 V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23
1 NA NA NA Smp Smp Tot Smp Smp Tot Smp Smp Tot Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp
  V24 V25 V26 V27 V28 V29 V30 V31 V32 V33 V34 V35 V36 V37 V38 V39 V40 V41 V42 V43 V44 V45
1 Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp
  V46 V47 V48 V49 V50 V51 V52 V53 V54 V55 V56 V57 V58 V59 V60 V61 V62 V63 V64 V65 V66 V67
1 Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Min Min Tot Smp Avg Smp Smp
  V68 V69 V70 V71 V72 V73 V74 V75 V76 V77 V78 V79 V80 V81 V82 V83 V84 V85 V86 V87 V88 V89
1 Smp Smp Avg Avg Avg Avg Avg Avg Avg Avg Tot Avg Avg Avg Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp Smp
  V90
1 Smp
> readLines(testfile.bin,n=1)
[1] "\"\",\"\",\"\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Tot\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Tot\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Tot\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Min\",\"Min\",\"Tot\",\"Smp\",\"Avg\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Avg\",\"Avg\",\"Avg\",\"Avg\",\"Avg\",\"Avg\",\"Avg\",\"Avg\",\"Tot\",\"Avg\",\"Avg\",\"Avg\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\",\"Smp\""
> seek(testfile.text)
[1] 2931
> seek(testfile.bin)
[1] 2428
> 2931-2428
[1] 503
> read.csv(testfile.text,header = FALSE,nrows = 1)
     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10   V11   V12   V13   V14   V15
1 ULONG ULONG ULONG IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4
    V16  V17   V18   V19   V20   V21   V22   V23   V24   V25   V26   V27   V28   V29   V30
1 IEEE4 BOOL IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4
    V31   V32   V33   V34   V35   V36   V37   V38   V39   V40   V41   V42   V43   V44   V45
1 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4
    V46   V47   V48   V49   V50   V51   V52   V53   V54   V55   V56   V57   V58   V59   V60
1 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4
    V61   V62   V63   V64   V65   V66   V67   V68   V69   V70   V71   V72   V73   V74   V75
1 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4
    V76   V77   V78   V79   V80   V81   V82   V83   V84   V85   V86   V87   V88   V89
1 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4 IEEE4
        V90
1 ASCII(16)

> readLines(testfile.bin,n=1)
[1] "\"ULONG\",\"ULONG\",\"ULONG\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"BOOL\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"IEEE4\",\"ASCII(16)\""
> seek(testfile.text)
[1] 3654
> seek(testfile.bin)
[1] 3152
> 3654-3152
[1] 502
```

same problem when using readLines also for text data:

```
> readLines(testfile.text,n=1)
[1] "\"TOB1\",\"Tower\",\"CR6\",\"7562\",\"CR6.Std.10.02\",\"CPU:EasyFlux_Tower.cr6\",\"22445\",\"Flux_CSIFormat\""
> readLines(testfile.bin,n=1)
[1] "\"TOB1\",\"Tower\",\"CR6\",\"7562\",\"CR6.Std.10.02\",\"CPU:EasyFlux_Tower.cr6\",\"22445\",\"Flux_CSIFormat\""
> seek(testfile.text)
[1] 601
> seek(testfile.bin)
[1] 95
```

Header and first datarow when opening in editor:

```
"TOB1","Tower","CR6","7562","CR6.Std.10.02","CPU:EasyFlux_Tower.cr6","22445","Flux_CSIFormat"
"SECONDS","NANOSECONDS","RECORD","FC_mass","FC_QC","FC_samples","LE","LE_QC","LE_samples","H","H_QC","H_samples","NETRAD","G","SG","energy_closure","poor_energy_closure_flg","Bowen_ratio","TAU","TAU_QC","USTAR","TSTAR","TKE","TA_1_1_1","RH_1_1_1","T_DP_1_1_1","amb_e","amb_e_sat","TA_2_1_1","RH_2_1_1","T_DP_2_1_1","e","e_sat","TA_3_1_1","RH_3_1_1","T_DP_3_1_1","e_probe","e_sat_probe","H2O_probe","PA","VPD","Ux","Ux_SIGMA","Uy","Uy_SIGMA","Uz","Uz_SIGMA","T_SONIC","T_SONIC_SIGMA","sonic_azimuth","WS","WS_RSLT","WD_SONIC","WD_SIGMA","WD","WS_MAX","CO2_density","CO2_density_SIGMA","H2O_density","H2O_density_SIGMA","CO2_sig_strgth_Min","H2O_sig_strgth_Min","P","ALB","SW_IN","SW_OUT","LW_IN","LW_OUT","T_nr_Avg","LW_IN_meas","LW_OUT_meas","PPFD_IN","sun_azimuth","sun_elevation","hour_angle","sun_declination","air_mass_coeff","daytime","TS_1_1_1","SWC_1_1_1","cs65x_ec_1_1_1","G_plate_1_1_1","shfp_cal_1_1_1","FETCH_MAX","FETCH_90","FETCH_55","FETCH_40","UPWND_DIST_INTRST","FP_DIST_INTRST","FP_EQUATION"
"SECONDS","NANOSECONDS","RN","mg m-2 s-1","Grade","samples","W m-2","Grade","samples","W m-2","grade","samples","W m-2","W m-2","W m-2","fraction","","fraction","kg m-1 s-2","grade","m s-1","deg C","m2 s-2","deg C","%","deg C","kPa","kPa","deg C","%","deg C","kPa","kPa","deg C","%","deg C","kPa","kPa","g/m^3","kPa","hPa","m s-1","m s-1","m s-1","m s-1","m s-1","m s-1","deg C","deg C","Decimal degrees","m s-1","m s-1","decimal degrees","decimal degrees","decimal degrees","m s-1","mg m-3","mg m-3","g m-3","g m-3","fraction","fraction","mm","%","W m-2","W m-2","W m-2","W m-2","Klvin","W m-2","W m-22","umolPhoton m-2 s-1","decimal degrees","decimal degrees","decimal degrees","decimal degrees","adimensional","fraction","deg C","%","dS m-1","W m-2","","m","m","m","m","m","%","authors"
"","","","Smp","Smp","Tot","Smp","Smp","Tot","Smp","Smp","Tot","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Min","Min","Tot","Smp","Avg","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Avg","Avg","Avg","Avg","Avg","Avg","Avg","Avg","Tot","Avg","Avg","Avg","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp"
"ULONG","ULONG","ULONG","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","BOOL","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","IEEE4","ASCII(16)"
|·<    ç  Î“f¾  A  ŒFÓÁ@À  A  ŒFL>  A  ŒFi3]Â=dÖ¿Ýè¿[øP= ð§»½Ç©V=  À@o>ŽzŸºoçD?\ÇqAõ.CB…•@¢JW?r¢Ü?ûÞ’Aõš BÆ³’@‚·Y?ÿ™@¨pAdÁB"ÒgApîÓ?:§Û?"/GAä”¡BLîJA§`á>ŒW??V1¿è‹]?­¾Œ½t‘>¶šA!¨²>    ‹À¢?ÀR?‹7—Cíè@B¨CfBñ%u@œm   D9Ì@åJÊ@nä“=µ9q?ÉF^?        ’X`À¼‹V?™©CÂC
CÑäRÂÚ#â¿    ^H
ýŠBìd•Âl|%ÃääAÿÿÿ    ×‚Ayž@Bh¡÷<
>¨3«A„œÆBòC5ßC?í×BVÕªD:BÅBKljun et al
```

Comment: So i found a solution which works by not using a text based fileconnection at all. I just read the lines i need as text from the binary file with `metadata <- readLines(file.bin)` and then use `read.csv(text = metadata,...)` to read these lines as table. Still courious about what the initial problem is caused by.

Comment: I think you re-title the question to something like `How to read Table Oriented Binary File in R`, and post your solution and accept it, as it will definitely help future searchers with this curious data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found a solution which works by not using a text based fileconnection at all.
I just read the lines i need as text from the binary file with

```
file.bin <- file(filepath,"rb")
metadata <- readLines(file.bin,n=1)
close(file.bin)
```

where `n` is the number of lines to be read and then use

```
read.csv(text = metadata,...)
```

to read these lines as table.

Still courious about what the initial problem is caused by. As @KJ described, it may be a problem with line endings which are different on unix and windows based systems.